# Combine Ember with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ember.js, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel & Ember.
And I sa some project that bulid like so:
All JavaScript Files found in laravel `app/assets` directiony, and also the hbs file.
When I get into the public index route its load a view with `include script` tags for all the files that found in the assets directiony.

So I want to know some things:

1) How I put `JS` and `hbs` files in this directiony and make them load from the broswer? cause I read that assets need to be putted in the `public` directiony?
2) How can I do manipulation on the `hbs` files ? meaning that I need to wrap the HandelBar template code in `Ember.compile` function?
3) If I want to use the newest version of Ember how do I write the code in client-side `JS` And not in ECA6 standart?
4) Which file of Ember I need to include in the view?

Comment: You want to do two seperate projects. You want laravel serving an API, and ember being your SPA frontend. Lots of pain will ensue if you attempt to combine the two into one project.

Comment: @DavidDuncan but finally projects should be merged into one site. How to do that?